# My CSS positioning is differing between Code Pen and Chrome

Tags: css

I have a small programme I'm writing for a virtual pet. Something's amiss with my CSS positioning. In Code Pen (https://codepen.io/JammyPiece/full/dBZaMP) everything sits fine.

![screenshot of everything in correct position]https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1562690535/blob_u4hiqo.jpg

But in Chrome, my small items are all the same distance out of place.
![screenshot of elements out of place]
https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1562690535/boboutofplace_vpw8fp.jpg

I don't know what to do- I'm hosting it in Code Pen but I need to know why it's not working in Chrome.

I've been reading about positioning. I'm happy with my positioning in Code Pen but my files are read in Chrome, the small items like heart, star and food items are all out of place. Is there anything that can be done so that both are in place? All the images are positioned relative.

```css
#heart {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    top: -970px;
    left: 400px;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    }
 #star {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
   top: -970px;
   left: 350px;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    position: relative;
   display: none;
}


 #hungry {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    position: relative;
    left: 330px;
   top: -970px;
   display: none;
    }

#age {
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  top: 180px;
  left: 100px;
  display: none;
}

#medicine {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: -870px;
  left: 150px;
  display: none;
   }

#toys {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top:-1000px;
  left:-50px;
  display: none;
  }

.action {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#food {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 440px;
  top: -1000px;
  display: none;
   }

#drink{
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 240px;
  top: -900px;
  display: none;
  }
```

See the attached screenshots to see the difference.

Comment: Please add the relevant code as text to the post itself, images are hard to debug. Also, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with JavaScript, and even less with window.location ...

Comment: I copied your code and run in my device and everything seems fine

Comment: Viewing your codepen in Chrome everything looks fine. Are you using an older version of Chrome or perhaps your code is cached?

Answer (score 0):

I went to your codepen on chrome, firefox and safari (on a mac) and it seems perfectly fine on all of them, but if you want to ensure that your icons don't collide with one another you can use: `position: absolute`

(Not enough reputation to post a comment)